Google Sheets API - Data Source schedule refresh
I am trying to write custom Python script that will create Google Sheets, add BigQuery data source and schedule the refresh of the data source.
I was able to complete the first two task - create sheets and add BigQuery data source, but I am not able to find a function in API documentation for scheduling the data source.
Could somebody please help me with that?
This is what I have so far:
    def add_bigquery_data_source(sheet_id, custom_query):
        body = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "addDataSource": {
                        "dataSource": {
                            "dataSourceId": "BigQuery",
                            "spec": {
                                "parameters": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "BigQuery"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "bigQuery": {
                                    "projectId": 'pfx-data',
                                    "querySpec": {
                                        "rawQuery": custom_query,
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "updateCells": {
                        "rows": {
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "dataSourceTable": {
                                        "dataSourceId": "BigQuery",
                                        "rowLimit": {
                                            "value": 1000000
                                        },
                                        "columnSelectionType": "SYNC_ALL"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "fields": "dataSourceTable",
                        "start": {
                            "sheetId": 0,
                            "rowIndex": 0,
                            "columnIndex": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
        url = f"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheet_id}:batchUpdate"
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))

I was able to create body of the funcion by this documentation:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#datasourcerefreshschedule
But I do not know what funciton to call in the JSON request and there to add it.
I beend trying to solve this for days but without success. Could anybody please help?

It appears you cannot currently set a schedule for a Connected Google Sheet through the Sheets API.
However, a workaround I used was using this request in a batchUpdate.
This does a one time refresh of all data sources, so running this code on a schedule (like as a Cloud Run Job) will essentially achieve the same thing.
body = {
"requests": [
    {
        "refreshDataSource": {
            "force": True,
            "isAll": True
        }
    }
],
"includeSpreadsheetInResponse": False,
"responseRanges": [],
"responseIncludeGridData": False
}

result = gsheets_service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(body=body, spreadsheetId='myspreadsheetid12345').execute()

Perhaps a feature request should be submitted to Google to get your original ask implemented.
